# Get current user array with post string

Tags: posts, users, array

I need to get 10 current user fields and pass the field values to a post string. The post string is expecting certain label names for each value.

Example - post string expects `'firstname' => 'value'`, not `'user_firstname' => 'value'`. After days of fatal parse errors for syntax, now I just get a fail status. Either my array code or post code, (or both), is somehow flawed. I read a post today from 2011 that says since WordPress 3.3 (current version now is 3.9), that the way custom user fields are called is different. The post > http://goo.gl/x5deHi says the way to call custom WP fields like 5 of mine are, is like this:

```
    if ( $current_user->has_prop( 'my-field' ) ) )
echo '<p>
    ' . $current_user->get( 'my-field' ) . '
    </p>';`
```

So this is the code I have right now:

```
    //Get values for these 10 user fields 
    function wp_get_current_user() {
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

    $current_user_info = array(
    'firstname' . $current_user->user_firstname =>' ',
    'lastname' .  $current_user->user_lastname =>' ',
    if ( $current_user->has_prop( 'mepr-address-one' ) ) )
    ' . $current_user->get( 'mepr-address-one' ) .  => ' ',
    if ( $current_user->has_prop( 'mepr-address-city' ) ) )
    ' . $current_user->get( 'mepr-address-city' ) .  => ' ',
    if ( $current_user->has_prop( 'mepr-address-state' ) ) )
    ' . $current_user->get( 'mepr-address-state' ) .  => ' ',
    if ( $current_user->has_prop( 'mepr-address-zip' ) ) )
    ' . $current_user->get( 'mepr-address-zip' ) .  => ' ',
    if ( $current_user->has_prop( 'mepr-address-country' ) ) )
    ' . $current_user->get( 'mepr-address-country' ) .  => ' ',   
    'email' . $current_user->user_email =>' ',
    'username' . $current_user->user_login =>' ',
    'password' . $current_user->user_pass =>' '

    );
    }
    // Generate the POST string
    // These last three lines aren't posting my get user values
    $postdata = '';
    foreach($query_vals as $key => $value){ 
$postdata .= $key.'='.urlencode($n=$value).'&';
    }
```

And the post string needs to meet the parameters described in the post that is this:

```
    foreach ( get_user_meta( $user->ID ) as $key => $values ) {
var_dump( $key, $values );
    }
```

But being a php newb, I'm not sure of the coding syntax. Don't I have to define has_prop before I can use it?

Comment: Two problems I can see quickly. Your global should be inside your function, not outside, and `Function` should be `function`

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a lot of errors. For example, inside you should define the `global $current_user`, not outside. Other error, you use `$query_vals` variable outside the function where that variable is not defined. Anyway, I would use the function [`wp_get_current_user()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_current_user) which have not to be called before [init action hook](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/init).

For example, if you are going to use the POST string as data for javascript:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse_scripts' );

function wpse_scripts() {

      $user_fields = wpse_get_current_user_info();
      $postdata = http_build_query( $user_fields );

      wp_localize_script( 'my_script', 'my_script_data', $postdata );

}

function wpse_get_current_user_info() {
      $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
      $current_user_info = array(
                    'firstname' => $current_user->user_firstname,
                    'lastname'  => $current_user->user_lastname,
                    //Add the rest of info you need
                    //In the forman key => value
                   );
      return $current_user_info;
}
```

In order to help you in a more specific way you should tell us where are you going to use the POST string and the context.

Basic example to send the user data to a server using WP HTTP API (Call  wpse_send_user_data when you need to get the response body after sending the user data to the third party service):

```
function wpse_send_user_data() {

      //You should check here if the request should be done
      //if( $some_control == true ) return;

      $uerdata = wpse_get_current_user_info();

      $args = array( 'method' => 'POST', 'body' => $uerdata );
      $request = wp_remote_request( 'http://www.example.com', $args )

      $response = wp_remote_retrieve_body($request);

      return $response;

}

function wpse_get_current_user_info() {
      $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
      $current_user_info = array(
                    'firstname' => $current_user->user_firstname,
                    'lastname'  => $current_user->user_lastname,
                    //Add the rest of info you need
                    //In the forman key => value
                   );
      return $current_user_info;
}
```

I prefer use WP HTTP API but if you want to use cURL:

```
function wpse_send_user_data() {

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://www.example.com/");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

    // Get userinfo array and set as POST fields
    $uerdata = wpse_get_current_user_info();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query( $uerdata ));

    // receive server response ...
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $server_output = curl_exec ($ch);

    curl_close ($ch);

    // further processing ....
    if ($server_output == "OK") { ... } else { ... }

}

function wpse_get_current_user_info() {
      $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
      $current_user_info = array(
                    'firstname' => $current_user->user_firstname,
                    'lastname'  => $current_user->user_lastname,
                    //Add the rest of info you need
                    //In the forman key => value
                   );
      return $current_user_info;
}
```

Comment: The purpose of the whole file is to generate a simple xml load string to securely register the new user via SSL at a third-party content provider website, so the user does not have to completely re-enter all of their user information again at that site and to eliminate the possibility of data mismatches.

Comment: I'm trying to help a long time friend who paid some developers a lot of $ and got a crap, incomplete WP site. This is one of the last pieces of code needed.

Comment: The original file had 16 static data fields in the array that looked like this:                                      'firstname' => 'Mary',                                'lastname' => 'Smith',                                      and the POST code looked like this:                     $postdata = '';
foreach($query_vals as $key => $value) {
 $postdata .= $key.'='.urlencode($value).'&';
}                                                            to automate things, I have to format the array and postdata code so the post string complies to process the now variable user data.

Comment: BTW, the third-party website is G-rated. The originating site is a consumer discounts membership website.

Comment: Once you have the array with the user info, [http_build_query](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) will generate the URL-encoded query string, so you don't need the foreach loop, just be sure to pass the array with the correct `key => value` pairs. How/where do you send the user data to the third party website?

Comment: cybnet - I'm not sure if I can use http_build_query. The user data is meant to be sent using some postdata coding and then does curl code, connects with the server and then there's a simplexml_load_string and I get a succeed or fail response. I'm struggling with the $postdata code right now and getting a fail response.

Comment: I think that your problem is not to use or not `http_build_query()`. In the code you posted you was builing an HTTP query string in the `foreach` loop, so, why don't can you to use `http_build_query()` if this function builds the same thing? Just be sure to pass the correct array with the correct `key = value` pairs.

Comment: cybnet - this is starting to make sense. So would you still say that I should use the first code you posted - add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse_scripts' );

function wpse_scripts() {

      $user_fields = wpse_get_current_user_info();
      $postdata = http_build_query( $user_fields );

      wp_localize_script( 'my_script', 'my_script_data', $postdata

Comment: No, the first code I posted was an example of using the data for javascript. I posted that example because I didn't know where the query string was to be used. Now that you have talked about cURL it is obvious that the query string are not going to be used with javascript.

Comment: See edited answer. In the new example I've coded an HTTP request using POST method with the [WP HTTP API](http://codex.wordpress.org/HTTP_API) instead of cURL.

Comment: thanks for your effort here. Much appreciated, but - two things - I can't change the way the xml file on the receiving server expects the data string or it will fail. And I just read a post from 2011 that says since WP 3.3 because I'm trying to get some custom usermeta fields, it looks like I have to have different code for the custom fields. The post is here > (http://goo.gl/x5deHi). So doesn't my code have to change for those custom mepr-field names I'm calling?

Comment: Do you have to send the data to the third party sever vie POST or GET method? You said something about POST, and the second example I posted use the POST method but now I think you needs to send the data via GET method. Until you explain better waht and how you have to send the data and what you expect to get in the response I won't give more code, sorry, I hope you understand.

Comment: Via POST method. Look at the end of the code at the top code post I did that has this  >                                  // Generate the POST string
// These last three lines aren't posting my get user values
$postdata = '';
foreach($query_vals as $key => $value){ 
$postdata .= $key.'='.urlencode($n=$value).'&';
}

Comment: That is what the code I posted do. I posted a new example code using cURL. Your question about "Get current user array with post string" is already answered but I think you have another problems.